# Ansible output formatting options

Tags: bash, output, ansible

Is there an option to format ansible output with the use of ansible (not any other scripts)? For instance

```
name: Show version
  sudo: true
  hosts: web_front_end
  tasks:
    - name: Create yum cache
      shell: yum makecache
    - name: Check the version of Portal
      shell: rpm -qa | grep portal
      register: portal
    - debug: msg={{portal.stdout}}
  tags:
    - portal
    - wfe
```

I would like to get only the

```
TASK: [debug msg={{portal.stdout}}]
```

part. Or even is there a way to get only the shell command output?

Comment: I know Ansible pretty well by now but have never seen any feature that could help you here.

Comment: You can just pipe Ansible's output and process it with perl/sed/awk/whatever bash tool that can do this... is there some problem with this approach? It would be really easy to get it out this way.

Comment: I know there is no problem in writing a python/ruby/perl/sed/awk/whatever tool to do that, but I wanted to make a Jenkins job and avoid any other scripts involved

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem in Jenkins, it can execute bash? If you have to call Ansible via `ansible host1 playbook.yml` you might as well pipe it's output to perl: `ansible host1 playbook.yml | perl -ne 'do_perl_magic_that_prints_only_what_you_want'`

Comment: This might be helpful as an example: `$ echo -e "TASK: [debug msg="MY_VERSION: {{1.2.3a}}" ]\nSomething from Ansible\nSomething else from Ansible output\n" | perl -ne '($portal) = $_ =~ /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g if /MY_VERSION/; END { print $portal; }'`... this will just print `1.2.3a`

Comment: @FRC, perhaps update your question and describe what your ultimate end-goal is? Are you trying to record Ansible run results into Jenkins log?

Comment: Looking for the same, I have big outputs that I cannot really read because of the `\r\n` part.

Answer (score 6):

I have a plugin to format the output. The gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/MatthiasWinkelmann/dcc6ea4f9edf88cee9996905dfb7184a) but the gist's gist is:

```
# Save as <folder with your playbook>/callback_plugins/<some name>.py
# Optionally use no_log: True on your playbook/roles/tasks to suppress other output

import sys
import pprint

class CallbackModule(CallbackBase):

    def log(self, host, category, data):
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2, stream=sys.stdout)
        pp.pprint(data)
```

Answer (score 4):

You basically have two choices.  One is to do what folks have described above, which is to pipe the output of the ansible command to things like perl, sed, awk, etc.

The second alternative is to write your own Python script that calls ansible directly.  Ansible is written in Python and as such you can call it directly from your own Python code. The Ansible documentation on its [Python API](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_api.html) provides details on how to do this.