# Ansible to give MYSQL table output

Tags: mysql, linux, ansible

I am trying to execute a Ansible one liner, which call a bash script from a remote server and then executes in local machine. The bash script actually fetch data from Database.

Is it possible for Ansible to give a Table formatted output?
I am just  pasting the column headers alone.

Thanks
Aravind

```
author_name  scheduled_start_time  scheduled_end_time  comment_data  name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse ansible output, there are only two ways, which both are hard and somewhat hacky. One is to use callback plugins, the other is to parse with sed/awk/perl/python/whatever you like. See [Ansible output formatting options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564811/ansible-output-formatting-options) for reference.

I think there is a cleaner solution: you can execute your script on remote machine, save its output in a file on the remote machine and then save it locally by using [fetch module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/fetch_module.html). After that you can process resulting files locally using [local action](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html).